# String Compare Not Returning Correct results

Tags: c++, string, binary-search-tree

I am trying to compare two strings.  One string will come from a variable which the user inputs.  The other string is accessed from a variable in a BST.  I have tried to use strcmp and compare.  I have some output that lists each variable to show that they are the same.  I also have the strcmp and compare values of comparing the word directly in comparison as well as comparing the variables. I can tell that my issue is with the accessed variable "root->data.getTitle()" because that is what is returning not equal to the direct comparison.  My BST is filled from a predefined text file.

BookTree.cpp

```
bool BookTree::isMatch(std::string key) {
    cout <<"\"" << root -> data.getTitle() << "\"" << endl;
    cout << key << endl;
    cout << (key.compare(root->data.getTitle())) << endl;
    cout << strcmp(key.c_str(), root->data.getTitle().c_str()) << endl;
    cout << (key.compare("Compilers")) << endl;
    cout << (root->data.getTitle().compare("Compilers")) << endl;
    if ((key.compare(root->data.getTitle())) == 0)
        return true;
    return findMatch(root, key);
}

bool BookTree::findMatch(Node* node, std::string key){
    if (node == NULL)
        return false;
    if ((node->data.getTitle().compare(key)) == 0)
        return true;
    bool searchLeft = findMatch(node->left, key);
    if (searchLeft)
        return true;
    bool searchRight = findMatch(node->right, key);
        return searchRight;
}
```

Current Output

```
Which book would you like to search for? Compilers
Compilers
Compilers
-1
-13
0
1
This book has not been found in the system.
```

I added quotes around my variable to see the output and there is unwanted whitespace.  I use getline to load values from the text file as some titles can have multiple words.  I looked around and was unsure of a better way to do this.  How can truncate my string to not contain the trailing white space?

newOutput

```
Which book would you like to search for? Compilers
"Compilers
Compilers
-1
-13
0
1
This book has not been found in the system.
```

Constructor

```
BookTree::BookTree(){
    string newExpression;
    size = sizeof(Book)/sizeof(Book[0]);
    ifstream inStream;
    string auth1, auth2, title, subject, publisher, bookType, blank;
    int numAvail;
    inStream.open("bookDat.txt");
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        getline (inStream, title);
        getline (inStream, auth1);
        getline (inStream, auth2);
        getline (inStream, subject);
        getline (inStream, bookType);
        getline (inStream, publisher);
        inStream >> numAvail;
        getline(inStream, blank);
        Book[x] = BookData(auth1, auth2, title, subject, publisher, numAvail, bookType);
        cout << Book[x] << endl;
    }
    makeTree();
}
```

Comment: Make sure there are no space following (or preceding) your strings. I’d recommend adding quotes when printing strings to make spaces visible.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - Thank you, I tried that and I am a bit more confused.  I get "Compilers with no second double quote.  I am editing my problem with what I found.

Comment: So we know what the problem is: your line ends in `“\r\n”` and you ended up reading the `’\r’` as part of your line. When printing the carriage return it gets you to the start of the line where it prints the second quote.

Comment: I guess, you are working on a UNIX-like system while the file (`"bookDat.txt"`) was produced on a Windows system: you can look at the actual content of the file using `od -c bookDat.txt | less`. This tool shows special characters, too. `std::getline()` stops when it sees a newline (`'\n'`), not upon spaces. BTW, you should *always* check input after reading and before using the result in any form.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The double quotes was an awesome way to start.  I ended up making a right trim function that read the first character and the last character and deleted the rest.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: I'm long enough in the business to have seen a few cases in production systems which ended up having trouble with whitespace in strings. Most people get entirely confused by these situations although log files generally do contain the necessary information, e.g., the "invisible" carriage return. Making them visible is a good start and I'd recommend to always print strings with quotes.